# Passing user permission from child to parent component with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am currently trying to past data from a function to a parent component and then to a child component.

I have a function called **FetchUserPermissions** which queries a mock database and returns a list of user permissions. I need to pass that list of permissions to the parenting root component **App** and then to a component which restricts the users ability to view different elements in the UI.

What I exactly struggling to do is, to pass my `response` from the fetch request, to the parenting component and then to the other children.

My login and user permissions are not the first page a user sees when he accesses the application. Therefore I can't pass them from the top of the component tree.

Here is my **FetchUserPermissions** function that I use to get the user permissions:

```
function FetchUserPermissions() {
  const userRole = localStorage.getItem("role");
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accesstoken");
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
      accesstoken: accessToken,
      role: userRole
    }
  };
  if (userRole !== null) {
    fetch(
      process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/authenticated/get-roles",
      requestOptions
    ).then(response => response.json());
    //set the response as a state.
    // So that state can be passed as props to the CAN component.
  } else {
    console.log("not loggedin === no user permissions.");
  }
}

export default FetchUserPermissions;
```

This is the **Can** component, which aims to restrict user views and abilities in the UI, based on the user role.

```
const check = (rules, role, action, data) => {
  const permissions = rules[role];

  if (!permissions) {
    // role is not present in the rules
    return false;
  }

  const staticPermissions = permissions.static;
  if (staticPermissions && staticPermissions.includes(action)) {
    // static rule not provided for action
    return true;
  }

  const dynamicPermissions = permissions.dynamic;

  if (dynamicPermissions) {
    const permissionCondition = dynamicPermissions[action];
    if (!permissionCondition) {
      // dynamic rule not provided for action
      return false;
    }

    return permissionCondition(data);
  }
  return false;
};

const Can = props =>
  check(rules, props.role, props.perform, props.data)
    ? props.yes()
    : props.no();

Can.defaultProps = {
  yes: () => null,
  no: () => null
};

export default Can;
```

I thought that maybe I could export the **FetchUserPermissions** component as a `Context` and pass the data that way but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

One thing I don't wanna do for sure is to call out the `fetch` request, each time the user uses the **Can** component, because that will put too much strain on the database.

Here is how the **Can** component will be used in different pages:

```
  <div className="home">
    <h1>Mock Admin Page...</h1>
    <h3>{mockDataFetched}</h3>
    <Can
      role={userRole}
      perform="dashboard-page:visit"
      yes={() => (
        <div>
          <h1>Admin Dashboard</h1>
        </div>
      )}
      no={() => (
        <div>
          <h1>Non Admin Dashboard</h1>
        </div>
      )}
    />
  </div>
);
```

If there is anything unclear about my question, I'll happily provide additional information. Thank you in advance.

------ EDIT -------

Here's my APP component, it contains only a **Switch** and **Router** Elements:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Where the main router is innitiated. */}
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="container">
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            {/* custom dummy page. to be removed.*/}
            <Route exact path="/page-one" component={CustomPage} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin-board" component={AdminPage} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

-------------- 2nd EDIT-------------------------------------------------------

After applying all the suggested changes, I keep getting:

```
./src/views/routes/Can.js
  Line 2:  'usePermissions' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: Can you add your  App component, so it will be helpful to answer, I think using context will be a better solution,because when you wrap with context all the child elements will be able to access you dont want to pass the props .

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS just made an edit and added the App.js component

Comment: I think in the app component you should have a ContextProvider which will wrap all the routes, and in that contextprovider you need to call the api and get the permissions. Since at the ContextProvider is wrapped by, you can directly access the context of permissions at the Can component level

Comment: That's what I thought initially as well, it's just that I don't know _how_ to do it exactly.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS any suggestions on how I can solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, using context here is a good idea:

```js
const PermissionsContext = React.createContext();

const usePermissions = () => useContext(PermissionsContext);

const PermissionsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const permissions = useMemo(() => /* call your function here */, []);

  return (
    <PermissionsContext.Provider value={ permissions }>
      { children }
    </Permissions>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <PermissionsProvider>
      ...
    </PermissionsProvider>
  );
}

const Can = ({ ... }) => {
  const permissions = usePermissions();

  ...
}
```

You also can retreive permissions lazyly:

```js
const PermissionsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const permissions = useRef({}).current;

  const getPermissions = useCallback(() => {
    if (!permissions.data) {
      permissions.data = /* call your function */;
    }

    return permissions.data;
  });

  return (
    <PermissionsContext.Provider value={ getPermissions }>
      { children }
    </Permissions>
  );
}

const usePermissions = () => useContext(PermissionsContext)();
```

Comment: can you show me how I can invoke it with my functions? I'm having difficulties understanding how this is supposed to be implemented.

Comment: also what is `useMemo` ? I see so many undefined stuff when I try to incorporate this in my code..

Comment: Also sorry Andres but your solution doesn't provide the necessary context. The `const Can = ({ ... }) => {
  const permissions = usePermissions();

  ...
}` is in a separate file which means that it doesn't have access to ` const permissions = usePermissions();`

Comment: I'm not sure what is not working for you - just replace `/* call your function here */` with `FetchUserPermissions()`.

Comment: `useMemo()` is a [react hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to memoize some function result. It needed here to prevent several calls to your `FetchUserPermissions()` function.

Comment: It doesn't matter where your components is placed. You just need to put both `<App />` and `<Can />` under the `<PermissionsProvider />` on any level of deep (wrapped with any number of components).